# grep first two rows for each unique variable in data frame

Tags: r

From the dataframe below I want to pick the **two** first lines for each unique identifier in `V5`. I am not sure where to start with this one.

```
> head(Up,1000)
                     V1          V2                 V3   V4              V5 V6   V7   V8     V9 V10    V11 V12
1     ENSG00000124357.8        NAGK  ENST00000418807.3 9606 hsa-miR-106a-5p  3  114  121 -0.726  99 -0.726  99
2    ENSG00000131351.10       HAUS8  ENST00000253669.5 9606 hsa-miR-106a-5p  3   27   34 -0.714  99 -0.714  99
3     ENSG00000108702.3        CCL1  ENST00000225842.3 9606 hsa-miR-106a-5p  3  139  146 -0.670  99 -0.670  99
4    ENSG00000189159.11         HN1  ENST00000476258.1 9606 hsa-miR-123a-5p  3  107  114 -0.667  99 -0.666  99
5    ENSG00000154640.10        BTG3  ENST00000339775.6 9606 hsa-miR-123a-5p  3  167  174 -0.665  99 -0.665  99
6    ENSG00000087494.11       PTHLH  ENST00000395872.1 9606 hsa-miR-123a-5p  3  291  298 -0.629  99 -0.629  99
7     ENSG00000197885.6     NKIRAS1  ENST00000388759.3 9606 hsa-miR-155a-5p  3  141  148 -0.628  99 -0.628  99
8    ENSG00000146826.10     C7orf43  ENST00000394035.2 9606 hsa-miR-155a-5p  3  491  498 -0.614  99 -0.613  99
9    ENSG00000117616.13     C1orf63  ENST00000243189.7 9606 hsa-miR-155a-5p  3   37   44 -0.585  99 -0.585  99
10    ENSG00000144583.4      MARCH4  ENST00000273067.4 9606 hsa-miR-155a-5p -2 1353 1359 -0.575  99 -0.575  99
11    ENSG00000213928.4        IRF9  ENST00000396864.3 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  305  312 -0.567  99 -0.567  99
12    ENSG00000072849.6       DERL2  ENST00000572834.1 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  253  260 -0.566  99 -0.566  99
13   ENSG00000155366.12        RHOC  ENST00000339083.7 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  268  275 -0.554  99 -0.552  99
14    ENSG00000179431.5        FJX1  ENST00000317811.4 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  771  778 -0.550  99 -0.550  99
15   ENSG00000067057.12        PFKP  ENST00000381125.4 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3   73   80 -0.547  99 -0.547  99
16    ENSG00000204923.3      FBXO48  ENST00000377957.3 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  159  166 -0.531  99 -0.531  99
17   ENSG00000120539.10       MASTL  ENST00000342386.6 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  246  253 -0.529  99 -0.529  99
```

Data

```
Up <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text="V1          V2                 V3   V4              V5 V6   V7   V8     V9 V10    V11 V12
1     ENSG00000124357.8        NAGK  ENST00000418807.3 9606 hsa-miR-106a-5p  3  114  121 -0.726  99 -0.726  99
2    ENSG00000131351.10       HAUS8  ENST00000253669.5 9606 hsa-miR-106a-5p  3   27   34 -0.714  99 -0.714  99
3     ENSG00000108702.3        CCL1  ENST00000225842.3 9606 hsa-miR-106a-5p  3  139  146 -0.670  99 -0.670  99
4    ENSG00000189159.11         HN1  ENST00000476258.1 9606 hsa-miR-123a-5p  3  107  114 -0.667  99 -0.666  99
5    ENSG00000154640.10        BTG3  ENST00000339775.6 9606 hsa-miR-123a-5p  3  167  174 -0.665  99 -0.665  99
6    ENSG00000087494.11       PTHLH  ENST00000395872.1 9606 hsa-miR-123a-5p  3  291  298 -0.629  99 -0.629  99
7     ENSG00000197885.6     NKIRAS1  ENST00000388759.3 9606 hsa-miR-155a-5p  3  141  148 -0.628  99 -0.628  99
8    ENSG00000146826.10     C7orf43  ENST00000394035.2 9606 hsa-miR-155a-5p  3  491  498 -0.614  99 -0.613  99
9    ENSG00000117616.13     C1orf63  ENST00000243189.7 9606 hsa-miR-155a-5p  3   37   44 -0.585  99 -0.585  99
10    ENSG00000144583.4      MARCH4  ENST00000273067.4 9606 hsa-miR-155a-5p -2 1353 1359 -0.575  99 -0.575  99
11    ENSG00000213928.4        IRF9  ENST00000396864.3 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  305  312 -0.567  99 -0.567  99
12    ENSG00000072849.6       DERL2  ENST00000572834.1 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  253  260 -0.566  99 -0.566  99
13   ENSG00000155366.12        RHOC  ENST00000339083.7 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  268  275 -0.554  99 -0.552  99
14    ENSG00000179431.5        FJX1  ENST00000317811.4 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  771  778 -0.550  99 -0.550  99
15   ENSG00000067057.12        PFKP  ENST00000381125.4 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3   73   80 -0.547  99 -0.547  99
16    ENSG00000204923.3      FBXO48  ENST00000377957.3 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  159  166 -0.531  99 -0.531  99
17   ENSG00000120539.10       MASTL  ENST00000342386.6 9606 hsa-miR-1323-5p  3  246  253 -0.529  99 -0.529  99")
```

Comment: `Up[ave(Up$V5, Up$V5, FUN = seq_along) %in% 1:2, ]`

Comment: `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(Up,Up$V5),head,2))` works too.

Answer (score 4):

If we need to get the first two rows based on the grouping variable "V5", one option is `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Up)`), grouped by "V5", get the first 2 rows with `head`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Up)[, head(.SD, 2) , by = V5]
```

---

Or use `slice` from `dplyr` after grouping by "V5".

```
library(dplyr)
Up %>%
   group_by(V5) %>%
   slice(1:2)
```

As @Frank mentioned in the comments (about the [bug](https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr/issues/10)),  when the initial dataset is `data.table`, if a particular "V5" have less than 2 elements, the output shows an additional NA row.  Though, it works if we are using `data.frame`.

The option that works for both `data.table` and `data.frame` would be (@Franks' comments)

```
Up %>%
    group_by(V5) %>%
    slice(head(seq_len(n()),2))
```

Comment: If you dont convert it to a data table, would the same dplyr code listed in the second code block work on the original code?  Nvm, you just edited it.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess  I assumed both of these codes are independent and the starting data is `data.frame`, however, `dplyr` codes should also work on `data.table`

Comment: Fair warning, though, there's an open bug https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr/issues/10 which means that if your `V5` has only 1 row, something weird might happen when slicing wiht 1:2 (but only if you use dplyr with a data.table). Could slice on head(row_number(), 2) maybe.

Comment: What is SD really?

Comment: @user2300940  `.SD` means `Subset of Data.table`.

Comment: @Frank I tried that option, but it is giving me error, while the `slice(1:2)` gives an extra NA row when the starting dataset is data.table

Comment: Huh, maybe the error is because row_number isn't available to slice. I'm pretty sure n() is, so head(seq_len(n()), 2) shouldn't throw an error

Comment: @Frank What happens with `do(head(., 2))`?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns  The `do` option works, but it would be a bit slow

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, the following should get you pretty close for your data.frame, Up:

```
# get the first unique row
UpFirstTwoRows <- which(!duplicated(Up[, "V5"]))
# get the adjacent row, dropping cases where only one unique row exists
UpFirstTwoRows <- sort(unique(c(UpFirstTwoRows, UpFirstTwoRows + 1)))

UpNew <- Up[UpFirstTwoRows,]
```

Answer (score 0):

LOGIC:

- Slice the data.frame based on unique names of given column.
- Get first desired number of rows of each sliced data.

ARGUMENTS

1. data: A data frame
2. col: A column name of data
3. num.rows: Numeric, indicating number of rows to be sliced after dividing the data based on unique values
4. list: logical, if true returns the list otherwise returns a data.frame

   ```
       fun <- function(data, col, num.rows, list = TRUE){
          d <- unique(data[[col]])
          dev.data <- lapply(d, FUN = function(i) { data[data[[col]] == i, ][1:num.rows, ]})
          if(!isTRUE(list)) { 
            return(do.call(rbind, dev.data)) 
          } else {return(dev.data)}
        }
   ```

EXAMPLE:

```
fun(iris, "Species", 2, FALSE)
fun(iris, "Species", 3, TRUE)
```